# shared_ptr<void> destructor called on nullptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a simple piece of code to load a shared library

```
  std::shared_ptr<void> hnld;
  hnld.reset( dlopen("libFoo.so", RTLD_NOW),dlclose);
  if(!hnld){
    std::cout << "Failed to load. "<< std::endl;
  }
```

When the library is loaded everything works right, but if it fails the message is displayed, however the code crashes when calling the destructor `dlclose`, which is expected as the object is invalid.
As `!hnld` is false, shouldn't know the smart pointer that the destructor shouldn't be called ?

**Note** I know how to solve this by using another destructor who check if the object is `nullptr` before calling `dlclose`. My question is: why does the shared pointer behave like this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr This documents the behavior but does not answer why.

Comment: The deleter for a shared_ptr has to be able to handle nullptr.  Since `dlclose` doesn't handle nullptr, you'll need a helper deleter that does the nullptr check for you.

Comment: ...and a simple lambda could do the job: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a498d69e7cbe8a9)